# Amount of sunlight and water for citrus tree

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, watering, sunlight

I got this the other day from the local plant shop. I have tried to inform myself how to take good care about it. I read that it is best to keep it outdoors if I can but right now I can't do that. I understand that it needs as much sunlight as possible and quite a lot of water, but can I just check in the soil of the plant that if it is not moist then I should pour water to it? Is it reasonable to give it more water as often as every other day, that is 3 times a week or would that be too much? If it loses and falls off a leaf, is that an indication that I gave it too much water?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrus can be hard to keep nice... I live in Utah where summer humidity can get down to 5% rh ... in the past when I tried to keep container citrus, it would get too dry and the leaves would drop, but the tree wouldn’t die.. I also know that they don’t like to be overwatered. You have a bit of a balancing act.. so things that make your life easier:
Bigger pot.
Free flowing potting mix.
Watering on a schedule but only if the soil feels dry.
Periodic indoor liquid fertilizer (even if you take it outside)

As with all plant try to introduce it to light slowly if you are taking it outside... an hour in the morning then bring it inside, 1.5 hours the next day... that gives the plant a chance to harden off.